# What verb tense should I use for situations that I don't know how long they will last?

Tags: grammar

What verb tense should I use for situations that I don't know if they will last forever?

We use the present simple for things that are permanent, for example

> *I live in the EU.*

And we use the present simple for things that are temporary, for example

> *I'm living in the EU.*

But what if I don't know if it will be like this forever or not?

Comment: We don't usually use the continuous verb form to describe things that are ***always*** true. So it's ***I am British, Water freezes at 0°C, I like candy***, NOT ***I am being British, Water is freezing at 0°C, I am liking candy.*** In your context, using the continuous form strongly implies I didn't in the past and/or won't in the future live in the EU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't change the tense.

*I currently live in the EU.*

or

*I am currently living in the EU.*

We can also say the following:

*As of now, I am living in the EU.*

All of the above indicate that the situation may be temporary.

---

**Example**

*As of now, I am living in the EU but there is a possibility I will move to the USA in a few months if they offer me the job I am hoping for.*